# How can I make multiple arrays with different words move across the game screen?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, canvas

So I am making a version of Flappy Bird where the bird has to catch certain vocab words. To this end, I am trying to make random words from an array scroll across the screen from right to left. So far, I only have  [object Object] scrolling across the screen, as can be seen in the attached picture. Note that I am using Canvas (ctx).

How can I edit/amend to my code so that I can have an array of vocab words scrolling across the screen in place of [object Object]

Here are the pertinent lines of my code:

```
//Stick

var Stick = function(x, y,) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; 
};

Stick.prototype.draw = function() {
    //??   
};

// random sticks distribution

var sticks = ["test", "boy", "house"];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {  
    sticks.push(new Stick(i * 161 + 200, Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 10 + 1)) + 10));
}

function draw() {


for (var i = 0; i < sticks.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillText(sticks[i], sticks[i].x, sticks[i].y)
        //beaver.checkForStickGrab(sticks[i]);
        sticks[i].x -= 1;
    }


}
```

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D05ew.png)

Comment: you should pass the sticks name to the Stick constructor as well, therefore you can pull it out elsewhere to draw it/display it

Comment: How exactly would I pass the sticks name to the constructor in order to display it to the canvas?

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra param which represents your name in the Stick constructor.

Using your for loop pass the names to the constructor.

`ctx.fillText` should accept the name as the first param I think which will be your text on the board.

```
//Stick

var Stick = function(x, y, name) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.name = name;
};

Stick.prototype.draw = function() {
  //??   
};

// random sticks distribution

var stickNames = ["test", "boy", "house"];
var sticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  sticks.push(new Stick(i * 161 + 200, Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 10 + 1)) + 10, stickNames[i]));
}

function draw() {

  for (var i = 0; i < sticks.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillText(sticks[i].name, sticks[i].x, sticks[i].y)
    //beaver.checkForStickGrab(sticks[i]);
    sticks[i].x -= 1;
  }


}
```